# iOS Swift how to add a shadow to a transparent UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Im using an UIView as an overlay with a drop shadow, however once I set the UIView background color to .clear, I no longer see the shadow, is there a way to add shadows to an UIView with clear background color?

Comment: Transparent objects don't cast shadows. Try using an image instead

Comment: That makes sense, I figured out another way to do the overlay which doesnt use transparent UIViews

Comment: @mding5692 did you managed to find a solution to this? If so then post your solution so others can use it in the future

Comment: Please find my answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56194429/8903877

Comment: the correct way to add shadows with a hole in the middle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59092828/294884

Answer (score -3):

Yes It is work by giving opacity layer less than 10

@IBInspectable var shadowOffsetX : CGFloat = 0

```
@IBInspectable var shadowOffsetY : CGFloat = 0

@IBInspectable var shadowColor : UIColor? {
    didSet{
        self.layer.shadowColor = shadowColor?.cgColor
    }
}

@IBInspectable var shadowOpacity : Float = 0 {
    didSet{
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
    }
}

@IBInspectable var shadowRadius : CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet{
        self.layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
    }
}

@IBInspectable var cornerRadius : CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet{
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}

@IBInspectable var borderWidth : CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet{
        layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    }
}

@IBInspectable var borderColor : UIColor? {
    didSet{
        layer.borderColor = borderColor?.cgColor
    }
}

@IBInspectable var layerOpacity : Float = 0 {
    didSet{
        self.layer.opacity = layerOpacity
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowOffsetX, height: shadowOffsetY)
}
```

Comment: pls add some information about why your answer is correct or what you do